# A qualifying exam problem about improper Riemann integration

Tags: integration, limits, solution-verification, fubini-tonelli-theorems

This is my solution to an old exam problem that I'd appreciate some feedback on. The problem:

> Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, $f\geq 0$ and $\int _0^{\infty} f(x) dx=L<\infty;$ that is, $f$ is Riemann integrable in any finite interval $[0,R]$ and $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty} \int _0^R f(x) dx$ exists. Show that
> $$
> \lim_{R\to \infty}\frac{\int_0^R x f(x)dx}{R}=0.
> $$

Proof:
Note that if $f\equiv 0$ there's nothing to prove. Else, we would like to apply L'Hôpital's Rule, but the problem is the integrand is not necessarily continuous, hence the integral is not differentiable in $R.$ To that end, we use Fubini's Theorem to rewrite as a double-integral:
$$
\int _0^R x f(x)\,dx = \int _0^R \int _0^x f(x)\,dydx
$$$$
= \int _0^R \int _y^R f(x)\; dxdy
$$Define $F(x):=\int _0^x f(t)\;dt;$ then $F$ is continuous. We have
$$
\int _0^R \int _y^R f(x)\; dxdy=\int _0^R F(R)-F(y)\;dy;
$$then we have
$$
\frac{\int_0^R x f(x)dx}{R}=\frac{\int _0^R F(R)-F(y)\;dy}{R} = F(R)-\frac{\int _0^R F(y)\,dy}{R}
$$ Here's the tricky part:

Since $f$ is integrable and non-negative, by assumption $F$ approaches $L$. This allows us to split up the limit:
$$
\lim_{R\to\infty}F(R) - \frac{\int _0^R F(y)\;dy}{R}  =\lim_{R\to\infty}F(R) - \lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{\int _0^R F(y)\;dy}{R} 
$$
$$
=L - \lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{\int _0^R F(y)\;dy}{R} 
$$ In this case, the remaining integral approaches $LR$. *Now* we can apply L'Hôpital's Rule:
$$
L-\lim_{R\to\infty} \frac{\int _0^R F(y)\;dy}{R} = L-\lim_{R\to \infty} F(R)=L-L=0. \square
$$Any comments/suggestions?

Comment: This is a nice generalization (+1).  The problem is often posed with $f$ continuous and solved with integration by parts.

Comment: It is more like $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = S$ implies $\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N n a_n = 0$. With $S_n = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j$ and summation by parts you have $\sum_{n=1}^N na_n = NS_N + \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} S_n$. Dividing by $N$ and taking the limit you get $S-S = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick $\epsilon>0$ and choose $T$ such that $\int_T^\infty f(x)dx < {1 \over 2} \epsilon$. Suppose $R >T$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^R {x \over R} f(x)dx &\le& \int_0^T {x \over R} f(x)dx + \int_T^\infty {x \over R} f(x)dx \\
&\le& {T \over R}\int_0^T {x \over T} f(x)dx + {1 \over 2} \epsilon \\
&\le& {T \over R} L + {1 \over 2} \epsilon
\end{eqnarray}
Now choose $R>{2 TL\over \epsilon}$ to get the desired result.

Comment: Wow, that is slick.

Answer (score 2):

For a very general approach, we have $f \in L^1([0,\infty))$ since $f$ is nonnegative and improperly Riemann integrable.

Thus, by the dominated convergence theorem,

$$\lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{1}{R}\int_0^R x f(x) \, dx = \lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{[0,\infty)}\frac{x f(x)}{R}\mathbf{1}_{[0,R]} \, dx = 0$$

Comment: I like this approach as well. The exam in question was...particular; it forbade usage of any complex analysis or measure theory, so I don't think this answer would have been accepted. But that's more a nitpick with the exam than your solution :).